# Gallery lag when change image

Tags: android, gallery

I try to use gallery to show image in network.
But when turn left or right to change image.
The image shows delay about 3 seconds to load from network each time.
May it load next image in background when this image showing.
Or save all loaded image in cache, but this may cause out of memory.
My code as below:

```
gallery = (MyGallery) this.findViewById(R.id.gallery_photo);
gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryViewerAdapter(this, URL));
```

URL is string array of URL.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this.mContext);
try {
URL aryURL = new URL(URL[i]);
URLConnection conn = aryURL.openConnection();
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
is.close();
iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
return iv;
}
```

How to modify my code can avoid load and lag each time?

Comment: an image grid is a better idea when showing multiple images from a remote connection ... i can help u in grid view

Comment: May image grid get the effect same as gallery while the finger move on screen?

Comment: this is how it looks: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/images/hello-gridview.png

Comment: Because I want to use gallery to show picture in full screen, and listen finger move on screen to previous or next one.

Comment: http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/implementing-a-lazy-loading-android-gallery-with-mirah/... tried this?

Comment: I don't know how to implement it in gallery. Any one can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyGallery extends Gallery {
    public MyGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams (android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return super.generateLayoutParams(p);
    }
}
```

Maybe you can try this.